# Ошибка при интернационализации прикладной программы Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Изучаю пример с применением интернационализации с помощью классов `ResourceBundle` и `ListResourceBundle`.

Пример демонстрирует применение комплектов ресурсов под именем семейства SampleRB.

После компиляции я постоянно получаю ошибку:

```
Английская версия программы: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ListResourceBundle.loadLookup(ListResourceBundle.java:202)
    at java.util.ListResourceBundle.handleGetObject(ListResourceBundle.java:130)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:441)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:407)
    at LRBDemo.LRBDemo.main(LRBDemo.java:12)
```

Сама программа состоит из класса **LRBDemo** с запускающим методом main-ом:

```
public class LRBDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // загрузить комплект ресурсов по умолчанию
        ResourceBundle rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRB");

        System.out.println("Английская версия программы: ");
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));

        // загрузить комплект ресурсов для поддержки немецкого языка
        rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRBde", Locale.GERMAN);

        System.out.println("\nНемецкая версия программы: ");
        System.out.println("Строка для ключа Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));
    }
}
```

Класса **SampleRB** с поддержкой английского языка:

```
public class SampleRB extends ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        Object[][]  resources = new Object[3][2];

        resources[0][0] = "title";
        resources[0][1] = "MyProgram";

        resources[1][0] = "StopText";
        resources[1][1] = "Stop";

        resources[1][0] = "StartText";
        resources[2][1] = "Start";

        return resources;
    }
}
```

И класса **SampleRBde** с поддержкой немецкого языка:

```
public class SampleRBde extends ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        Object[][] resources = new Object[3][2];

        resources[0][0] = "title";
        resources[0][1] = "Mein Programm";

        resources[1][0] = "StopText";
        resources[1][1] = "Anschlag";

        resources[2][0] = "StartText";
        resources[2][1] = "Anfang";

        return resources;
    }
}
```

Сам код не отображает ошибок, но если я пропишу в классе **LRBDemo** вместо строки `ResourceBundle rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRB")` таким образом `ResourceBundle rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("SampleRB")` и вместо `rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRBde", Locale.GERMAN);` так `rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("SampleRBde", Locale.GERMAN);`, то есть убираю пакет классов, то получаю на выводе:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name SampleRB, locale ru_RU
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
    at LRBDemo.LRBDemo.main(LRBDemo.java:9)
```

Структура моего проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду благодарен за совет, как убрать ошибки и вывести наконец результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Исправил индексы:

вместо

```
resources[1][0] = "StartText";
resources[2][1] = "Start";
```

так

```
resources[2][0] = "StartText";
resources[2][1] = "Start";
```

2)

```
public class LRBDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // загрузить комплект ресурсов по умолчанию
        ResourceBundle rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRB");

        System.out.println("Английская версия программы: ");
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));

        // загрузить комплект ресурсов для поддержки немецкого языка
        rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LRBDemo.SampleRBde", Locale.GERMAN);

        System.out.println("\nНемецкая версия программы: ");
        System.out.println("Строка для ключа Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));
    }
}
```

или

```
public class LRBDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // загрузить комплект ресурсов по умолчанию
        ResourceBundle rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle(SampleRB.class.getName());

        System.out.println("Английская версия программы: ");
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));

        // загрузить комплект ресурсов для поддержки немецкого языка
        rd = ResourceBundle.getBundle(SampleRBde.class.getName());

        System.out.println("\nНемецкая версия программы: ");
        System.out.println("Строка для ключа Title: " + rd.getString("title"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StopText: " + rd.getString("StopText"));
        System.out.println("Строка по ключу StartText: " + rd.getString("StartText"));
    }
}
```